# output is not correct(Swapping the first and last digit of a number)

Tags: java, loops

the output is almost correct except the first digit is not being removed.
the code should swap the first and last digit of the number for example - if the input is 756 it should give 657 as output right now the code is showing 7657 the first digit is not being removed. –

```
package questionsOnLoops;
import java.lang.Math; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OSJIDS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Scanner srv = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter any number: ");
        int n = srv.nextInt();
        
        int temp = n; //input number
        int c = 0;
        int f =n; //first digit
        int l; //last digit
        int result;
        
        while(temp>0) {
            temp = temp/10;
            c = c+1;
        }
        while(f>=10) {
            f = f/10;
        }
        g = n%10;
        result = (n/10)*10+f;
        result = (int) ((result%Math.pow(10,c))+(g*Math.pow(10,c)));
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation of what the code is supposed to do? with an examle and the expected result

Comment: Yoni is correct here. On Stackoverflow, we try not to just add blocks of code and expect others to do the work for you. Give some information on what the inputs are or what you expect the output to be and what it is currently.

Comment: the code should swap the first and last digit of the number for example - if the input is 756 it should give 657 as output right now the code is showing 7657 the first digit is not being removed.

Comment: I am trying to read through your code to understand what it does, but it’s hard. Please try with better variable names.

Comment: @user15244370 The two `while` loops don’t run the same number of times, so joining them isn’t trivial and would likely lead to harder to read code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes it quite hard to see what is exectly happening.

There are a few problems I see in your code (next to readability).
You were able to detect the first and the last number, but getting to the result seems to contain some mistakes

- `result = (input/10)*10+f;` here you take the input (506), you divide it by 10, multiply it by 10 to **abuse** the the int so that your fractions are removed and restored to the original number. Then you append the first number again.
- With the calculation you did above, you removed the last number, and added the first number as the last number. You are still missing the step to add the first number. It would be easier and better to just create a new number based on your calculations

### Calculating the new number

You already have most of the ingredients to calculate the new number.
You already have the firstDigit and the last digit calculated. To get to the result we take the last number, and multiply it with 10 until it's in the correct position to be first.
Next we append the first number, so that it's last in our new number
finally, we add the inbetween numbers again. (you can calculate the inbetween numbers by removing the first and last number from the original input)

I've updated your code example with the above mentioned changes. I've also gave the variables a bit more clear names to indicate what they contain

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner srv = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter any number: ");
    int input = srv.nextInt();        
    int temp = input;
    int length = 0;
    int firstDigit =input;
    int lastDigit;
    int inbetweenNumbers;

    while(temp>0) {
        temp = temp/10;
        length = length+1;
    }
    while(firstDigit>=10) {
        firstDigit = firstDigit/10;
    }
    lastDigit = input%10;

    inbetweenNumbers = input - lastDigit;
    inbetweenNumbers -= firstDigit * (int)Math.pow(10,length-1);

    //calculating the result
    int result = 0;
    result += lastDigit * (int)Math.pow(10,length-1);
    //Add last number (first digit of the input)
    result += firstDigit;
    //add the other numbers back
    result+= inbetweenNumbers;
    
    System.out.println(result+" "+length);
}
```

Comment: I agree that your code is much more readable. I’m afraid that you are spoon-feeding a bit too much. The OP would learn more if you explained his or her mistake and possibly hinted at a way to fix it.

Comment: On [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) they suggest *It's usually better not to provide a complete code sample if you believe it would not help the student, using your best judgment. … you may come back after a suitable amount of time and edit your response to include more complete code.* You may consider something along these lines, even though we don’t know whether this is homework. The OP seems to be a learner (aren’t we all?)

Answer (score 0):

Let’s use your example input, 756.

This gets rid of the last digit, 6, and instead puts the first digit there:

```
        result = (n/10)*10+f;
```

So now `result` is 757. Next you try to put the 6 where the first 7 is:

```
        k = (int) ((result%Math.pow(10,c))+(g*Math.pow(10,c)));
```

This isn’t quite correct. `c` is 3, the number of digits. So `Math.pow(10,c)` equals 1000.0. But you needed to use 100 in those two places, first to get rid of the `7` and then to add the `6` there. Try subtracting 1 from `c` in the expression.

**My suggestions for more readable code**

- Don’t declare a variable until you use it; inirialize each in the declaration.
- Use better variable names. For example:

  - `input` rather than `n`
  - `length` or `numberOfDigits` instead of `c`
  - `firstDigit` instead of `f`
  - `lastDigit` instead of `g`
  - `lastDigitReplaced` instead of `result`
  - `finalResult` instead of `k`

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend making your variables a bit more descriptive, but that is an easy fix. I am guessing from your title that you want to swap the first and last digits? This method converts the numbers to strings, making appends and insertions relatively easier in this case.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner srv = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.println("Enter any number: ");
        int num = srv.nextInt();
        int lastDig = num;
        int firstDig = num%10;

        int len = 0;
        while(lastDig>9) {
            lastDig/=10;
            len++;
        }
    
        String ans = Integer.toString(num).substring(1, len);
        ans = firstDig+ans+lastDig;
        System.out.println(ans);
            
    }
}
```